How can I display the complete coordinates with ‘\addplot graphics’ on the respective axes in TIKZ?
I use ‘tikz’ and plot an ‘eps’ file in an axis.   In the axis I place a coordinate system around this image.
Now I have the problem that the last numbers (3 and 2.7) are not displayed in the x- and y-file.

I have tried all the ideas that seem sensible and nonsensical to me. I am now at a loss. Can you give me a tip?
Code: (Unfortunately, I have not found a way to upload the eps file here. Or was I just blind? Here is an external link to the eps file)
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
                                    enlargelimits=false, 
                                    axis on top, 
                                    width=0.85\textwidth,height=0.5\textwidth,
                                    xlabel={Position $m$},
                                    ylabel={US $m$},
                                    ytick={0, 0.6, ..., 3},
                                    xtick={-2.720,-2.176, ..., 2.720},
                                    every x tick label/.append style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,zerofill,precision=1}, 
                                ]
                                    \addplot graphics [xmin=-2.720,xmax=2.720,ymin=0,ymax=3] {vp.eps};
        \end{axis}
        
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}    
    
\end{document}

I have an additional question: Do you see the white border at the top of the picture? How can I remove this? It is not included in the image and seems to come from incorrect programming?
Best regards
data
